# Multiple display languages in Office 2010

Tags: language, microsoft-office-2010

I'm looking to use multiple display languages as set in the title: I need to specify the language for each office program separately, somehow.

For example, I want to use English Display Language for MS Project and Danish Display Language for Outlook.  Is this even possible? All I see is when I change the language of project, it does the same for all of the other Office programs. I've searched on the web but not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. The only thing you can do is to install another version of MS Project (say, 2013) side-by-side with existing 2010 version for other programs. Then you'll get the ability to set language preferences for 2013 and 2010 sets separately.